# Access advanced search result

Tags: yii

I am building a Yii application and I followed a tutorial to enable the Advanced search in the index file of a table like this:

```
<?php
/* @var $this TakeController */
/* @var $dataProvider CActiveDataProvider */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
        'Takes',
);

$this->menu=array(
        array('label'=>'Create Take', 'url'=>array('create')),  
        array('label'=>'Manage Take', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $.fn.yiiListView.update('takelistview', {        
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Takes</h1>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php  $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'id'=>'takelistview',
        'sortableAttributes'=>array('id', 'data'')
)); ?>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to process the output of the advanced search. I know that with $dataprovider I can access all the records for this table, but I want to access only the filtered ones. In particular, I want to get the attribute "data" for each record in order to enable the download for all filtered records. I took a look at $.fn.yiiListView and CListView but I don't understand what to do. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the `$dataProvider` variable belongs to the `CDataProvider` class, you can access the data using the getdata Function as below.

```
$data = $dataProvider->getData($refresh);
```

Set the `$refresh` flag to true if you want to reload the data from data source

Refer to full data provider [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) for more dataProvider methods

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The problem is that this search updates the list without reloading the page, so I can't use php...indeed, if I echo the count of `$dataProvider->getData(true)` I get the total number of records. I need a way to access the updated list :/